# Is the .AspNet.Application cookie vulnerable to CSRF attacks?

Tags: web-application, cookies, csrf, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application that has undergone SAST. The scan detects a potential XSRF/CSRF vulnerability.

The application rewrites the `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie` setting `SameSite=Strict`:

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Cookies.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (string s in Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
        {
            if (s.ToLower() == ".aspnet.applicationcookie")
            {
                
                HttpCookie c = Request.Cookies[s];
                c.Value = Request.Cookies[s].Value;
                c.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                Response.Cookies.Set(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The SAST tooling (Checkmarx) doesn't like this, as we're essentially reading the cookie value willy-nilly and not performing any sanitation. The framework sets this cookie; if I try to modify the cookie, .NET will choke due to tampering.

I am unsure if there's a way to modify the cookie and have the application parse potentially harmful data. I don't think there, but this is all new to me, and I am learning as I go.

Is it safe to assume this is just noise?

Comment: Welcome to the community. What about `HttpOnly` and `secure`? Also, you're using ASP.NET Core or what specifically?

Comment: HttpOnly and Secure are set for this cookie. It's an older application, .NET 4.8 using MVC.

Comment: So the Windows only .NET framework 4.8? I've apparently only worked with .NET Core 6

Comment: ASP.NET doesn't have a 4.x version.  4.8 is .NET Framework.  (ASP.NET could use some of this framework server side but it doesn't need it with "core" asp.net versions.)  My big question here is why you are modifying the cookies at all.  ASP.NET should set them in a secure manner.  Also be sure to use the built-in anti-forgery cookies/tokens as Christiaan mentioned in his answer.

Comment: The cookie is being modified as it requires SameSite setting against it., the framework does not set SameSite as a default. Luckily I came across another part of the process (OWIN) with offers a mechanism for setting SameSite that doesn't mean rewriting the cookie in the way presented within the post.

Answer (score 2):

From the [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-02#section-8):

> "SameSite" cookies offer a robust defense against CSRF attack when
> deployed in strict mode, and when supported by the client.  It is,
> however, prudent to ensure that this designation is not the extent of
> a site's defense against CSRF, as same-site navigations and
> submissions can certainly be executed in conjunction with other
> attack vectors such as cross-site scripting.
>
> Developers are strongly encouraged to deploy the usual server-side
> defenses (CSRF tokens, ensuring that "safe" HTTP methods are
> idempotent, etc) to mitigate the risk more fully.
>
> Additionally, client-side techniques such as those described in
> [[app-isolation](http://www.collinjackson.com/research/papers/appisolation.pdf)] may also prove effective against CSRF, and are
> certainly worth exploring in combination with "SameSite" cookies.

So SameSite cookies are supposed to prevent CSRF, but it is still good practice to implement other security measures like [AntiForgeryToken](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks#anti-forgery-tokens-in-aspnet-mvc) for .NET MVC.

***Footnote**: It is always possible for clients to tamper with cookies. Data inside cookies should be considered user input and be sanitized and validated wherever it is used*

Comment: thanks. I'm using AntiForgeryToken and whatnot. I don't think there's real cause for concern here, I just want to ensure that's the case. I found a different way to set SameSite which doesn't involve rewriting the cookie.

Comment: *[...] same-site navigations and submissions can certainly be executed in conjunction with other attack vectors such as cross-site scripting.* About this, see https://jub0bs.com/posts/2021-01-29-great-samesite-confusion/